# создание главного меню для 2d игры и настройка разрешение экрана (unity)

Tags: c#, unity3d

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Подскажите пожалуйста хорошую статью на тему "создание главного меню для 2d игры"

А также есть вопрос, как сделать что бы при изменении разрешения экрана спрайты оставались на месте(и желательно без потери качества).

За ранее спасибо)

Comment: С меню я разобрался, а вот с разрешением экраны у меня проблемы.
При попытки изменить разрешение экрана, текст и некоторые спрайты либо исчезают либо уплывают в сторону.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для адаптивного меню в юнити для ui объектов есть специальные якоря,которые позволяют размещать ваши элементы в процентном соотношении к сторонам экрана

Например,если ширина экрана 400,а ваш объект на позиции 100 от левого угла,т е 1/4 от экрана(25%),то при экране 800,он пересчитает координаты и будет снова на 25% экрана,но уже 0.25 * 800 = 200

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вы можете настроить ваши якоря (Anchors) вручную либо автоматически относительно любого угла и задать параметр расширения его относительно каких-либо сторон

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]